# Game Controllers In A Web Application UI

Tags: java, browser, usb

I suppose I'm essentially asking if it's possible to write a browser plugin (in java, most likely) that can.

1; Read from the USB.
2; Determine if a device connected to a given USB port is a gamecontroller.
3; Interpret the USB stream, and make it possible to listen for events in Javascript...

If you feel that my question needs more detail, then please feel free to add it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You speak about a joystick ?

[there is jinput](http://java.net/projects/jinput/)

The applet can communicate with the javascript with [JSObject](http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/1.3/docs/jsobject.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin that already does this: [`javascript-joystick`](http://code.google.com/p/javascript-joystick/)

So, it seems that this is possible.